# I'm trying to create a temporary file for a dataset

Tags: python, module, dataset

I'm trying to use someone else's code to download the MNIST dataset into a temporary (tmp) location but I'm getting `No such file or directory: ...`

I tried adding the commented out line below to force it to create a dir but it should be creating a file.

```
def fetch(url):
    import requests, gzip, os, hashlib, numpy
#     os.makedirs("/tmp"+ hashlib.md5(url.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), exist_ok=True)
    fp = os.path.join('/tmp', hashlib.md5(url.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
    if not os.path.isfile(fp):
        with open(fp, "rb") as f:
            dat = f.read()
    else:
        with open(fp, "wb") as f:
            dat = requests.get(url).content
            f.write(dat)
    return numpy.frombuffer(gzip.decompress(dat), dtype=np.uint8)
X_train = fetch('http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz')[0x10:].reshape((-1, 28, 28))
Y_train = fetch('http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz')[8:]
X_test = fetch('http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz')[0x10:].reshape((-1, 28, 28))
Y_test = fetch('http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz')[8:]
```

My full error is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-dd8a9f8c88af> in <module>
     11             f.write(dat)
     12     return numpy.frombuffer(gzip.decompress(dat), dtype=np.uint8)
---> 13 X_train = fetch('http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz')[0x10:].reshape((-1, 28, 28))
     14 Y_train = fetch('http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz')[8:]
     15 X_test = fetch('http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz')[0x10:].reshape((-1, 28, 28))

<ipython-input-9-dd8a9f8c88af> in fetch(url)
      4     fp = os.path.join("/tmp", hashlib.md5(url.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
      5     if not os.path.isfile(fp):
----> 6         with open(fp, "rb") as f:
      7             dat = f.read()
      8     else:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/23278f029ff68f1e993776e500ce06b9'
```

The code comes from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRlyw6LO5qo&t) by Geohotz

Comment: "If generated filename is **not** a file, open it for reading" - removing the "not" from the if should help you out.

Comment: I thought that's what the `else` was for.

Comment: No, wait, that works. I took it apart and see that you are right. I wonder why George Hotz had this in his code. It's in the link in the OP at the beginning of the video. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is by noticing that when the file with the given filename is not present on disk, we create it using x flag in open function. Something like this

```
if not os.path.isfile(fp):
    open(fp, "x")
with open(fp, "wb") as f:
    dat = requests.get(url).content
    print("Writing ", dat)
    f.write(dat)
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#open) is the reference of open() function in python3